# Extract all the child nodes for a parent node from turtle file using SPARQL

Tags: sparql

I have following concepts in turtle file. I would like to extract preferred label and ids for parent node (DOID_4159) and all its child from below concepts. I have written following SPARQL query to fetch the information, but it will not give all the child nodes.

```
qres = g.query(
    """
    SELECT *
    WHERE {
    {?s skos:prefLabel ?prefLabel .
    ?s skos:broader  <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_4159>  . 
    }
    UNION
    {?s skos:prefLabel "skin cancer"@en .
    ?s skos:prefLabel ?prefLabel .
    }
    }
    """)
```

```
<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_8923>
      a       skos:Concept ;
      skos:altLabel "malignant scalp melanoma"@en , "malignant lip melanoma"@en , "malignant melanoma of skin of upper limb"@en , "cutaneous melanoma"@en , "malignant melanoma of ear and/or external auricular canal"@en , "malignant trunk melanoma"@en , "malignant melanoma of skin of trunk except scrotum"@en , "malignant lower limb melanoma"@en , "malignant melanoma of skin of lower limb"@en , "malignant upper limb melanoma"@en , "malignant ear melanoma"@en , "malignant neck melanoma"@en ;
      skos:broader <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_4159> ;
      skos:definition "A skin cancer that has_material_basis_in melanocytes." ;
      skos:inScheme <https://localhost:8443/ontology/Applicanttest/APPLICANTTEST> ;

<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_3451>
      a       skos:Concept ;
      skos:altLabel "carcinoma of skin"@en ;
      skos:broader <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_4159> ;
      skos:definition "A skin cancer that is located_in tissues of the skin and develops from epithelial cells." ;
      skos:inScheme <https://localhost:8443/ontology/Applicanttest/APPLICANTTEST> ;
      skos:prefLabel "skin carcinoma"@en .
<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_6944>
      a       skos:Concept ;
      skos:altLabel "Seborrheic Keratosis of Vulva"@en ;
      skos:broader <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_6498> , <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_4159> ;
      skos:inScheme <https://localhost:8443/ontology/Applicanttest/APPLICANTTEST> ;
      skos:prefLabel "vulvar seborrheic keratosis"@en .
<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_4159>
      a       skos:Concept ;
      skos:altLabel "malignant neoplasm of skin"@en , "CA - skin cancer"@en , "melanoma and Non-melanoma skin cancer"@en ;
      skos:broader <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_37> ;
      skos:definition "An integumentary system cancer located_in the skin that is the uncontrolled growth of abnormal skin cells." ;
      skos:inScheme <https://localhost:8443/ontology/Applicanttest/APPLICANTTEST> ;
      skos:prefLabel "skin cancer"@en .
<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_11684>
      a       skos:Concept ;
      skos:broader <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_6498> ;
      skos:inScheme <https://localhost:8443/ontology/Applicanttest/APPLICANTTEST> ;
      skos:prefLabel "melanoacanthoma"@en .
```

```
Following is the desired output:
id        label
DOID_8923 skin melanoma
DOID_3451 skin carcinoma
DOID_6944 vulvar seborrheic keratosis
DOID_4159 skin cancer
DOID_6498 seborrheic keratosis
DOID_11684 melanoacanthoma
```

If I would like to fetch this information for parent (DOID_4159) and all its associated nodes, how can I achieve this? I am new to SPARQL, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: what exactly is missing? and how is `DOID_11684` related to `DOID_4159`? I mean, there is no path in your sample data

Comment: anyway, for transitive you have to use SPARQL property path operator asterisk (`*`) or plus (`+`), i.e. you do `?s skos:broader*  <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_4159>  .`

Comment: DOID_11684 is a child node of DOID_4159 but not a direct child node. So you mean to say, if there is no direct path between these two, it is not possible to capture this information. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here we have some issues

- The .ttl file you posted is not correct. There is an error on the definition of the 1st entity which is missing of the `.` at the end. So you have to update the definition from:

```
<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_8923>
      a       skos:Concept ;
      skos:altLabel "malignant scalp melanoma"@en , "malignant lip melanoma"@en , "malignant melanoma of skin of upper limb"@en , "cutaneous melanoma"@en , "malignant melanoma of ear and/or external auricular canal"@en , "malignant trunk melanoma"@en , "malignant melanoma of skin of trunk except scrotum"@en , "malignant lower limb melanoma"@en , "malignant melanoma of skin of lower limb"@en , "malignant upper limb melanoma"@en , "malignant ear melanoma"@en , "malignant neck melanoma"@en ;
      skos:broader <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_4159> ;
      skos:definition "A skin cancer that has_material_basis_in melanocytes." ;
      skos:inScheme <https://localhost:8443/ontology/Applicanttest/APPLICANTTEST> ;
```

To:

```
<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_8923>
      a       skos:Concept ;
      skos:altLabel "malignant scalp melanoma"@en , "malignant lip melanoma"@en , "malignant melanoma of skin of upper limb"@en , "cutaneous melanoma"@en , "malignant melanoma of ear and/or external auricular canal"@en , "malignant trunk melanoma"@en , "malignant melanoma of skin of trunk except scrotum"@en , "malignant lower limb melanoma"@en , "malignant melanoma of skin of lower limb"@en , "malignant upper limb melanoma"@en , "malignant ear melanoma"@en , "malignant neck melanoma"@en ;
      skos:broader <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_4159> ;
      skos:definition "A skin cancer that has_material_basis_in melanocytes." ;
      skos:inScheme <https://localhost:8443/ontology/Applicanttest/APPLICANTTEST> .
```

The `.` at the end, it means that the definition of your entity is complete. While the `;` is used when you need to add other relationships.

- The record DOID_8923 has no `skos:prefLabel` so, you are not able to retrieve the prefLabel from DOID_8923. You need to add the `skos:prefLabel` also to this entity
- As already pointed out by [UninformedUser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4744359/uninformeduser)
  you have to specify the relation between `DOID_11684` and `DOID_4159` also in your schema

Here you can find your `.ttl` file updated and the transitive SPARQL query

```
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> .

<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_8923>
      a       skos:Concept ;
      skos:altLabel "malignant scalp melanoma"@en , "malignant lip melanoma"@en , "malignant melanoma of skin of upper limb"@en , "cutaneous melanoma"@en , "malignant melanoma of ear and/or external auricular canal"@en , "malignant trunk melanoma"@en , "malignant melanoma of skin of trunk except scrotum"@en , "malignant lower limb melanoma"@en , "malignant melanoma of skin of lower limb"@en , "malignant upper limb melanoma"@en , "malignant ear melanoma"@en , "malignant neck melanoma"@en ;
      skos:broader <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_4159> ;
      skos:definition "A skin cancer that has_material_basis_in melanocytes." ;
      skos:inScheme <https://localhost:8443/ontology/Applicanttest/APPLICANTTEST> .

<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_3451>
      a       skos:Concept ;
      skos:altLabel "carcinoma of skin"@en ;
      skos:broader <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_4159> ;
      skos:definition "A skin cancer that is located_in tissues of the skin and develops from epithelial cells." ;
      skos:inScheme <https://localhost:8443/ontology/Applicanttest/APPLICANTTEST> ;
      skos:prefLabel "skin carcinoma"@en .
<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_6944>
      a       skos:Concept ;
      skos:altLabel "Seborrheic Keratosis of Vulva"@en ;
      skos:broader <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_6498> , <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_4159> ;
      skos:inScheme <https://localhost:8443/ontology/Applicanttest/APPLICANTTEST> ;
      skos:prefLabel "vulvar seborrheic keratosis"@en .
<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_4159>
      a       skos:Concept ;
      skos:altLabel "malignant neoplasm of skin"@en , "CA - skin cancer"@en , "melanoma and Non-melanoma skin cancer"@en ;
      skos:broader <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_37> ;
      skos:definition "An integumentary system cancer located_in the skin that is the uncontrolled growth of abnormal skin cells." ;
      skos:inScheme <https://localhost:8443/ontology/Applicanttest/APPLICANTTEST> ;
      skos:prefLabel "skin cancer"@en .
<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_11684>
      a       skos:Concept ;
      skos:broader <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_6498> ;
      skos:inScheme <https://localhost:8443/ontology/Applicanttest/APPLICANTTEST> ;
      skos:prefLabel "melanoacanthoma"@en .
```

SPARQL

```
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> 

SELECT *

WHERE {?s skos:broader*  <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_4159>;
          
          skos:prefLabel ?prefLabel 
         }
```

```
s                                           prefLabel
<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_4159>  skin cancer
<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_3451>  skin carcinoma
<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_6944>  vulvar seborrheic keratosis
```

Comment: Is there a way to select the variable in select instead of 'select *'

Comment: eg. select doid, preferred label

Comment: ```SELECT ?s ?prefLabel```

Comment: to use ```did``` as variable you need to modify the SPARQL query as follows

```prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> 

SELECT ?doid ?prefLabel

WHERE {?doid skos:broader*  <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_4159>;
          
          skos:prefLabel ?prefLabel 
         }```

Comment: Actually the above query worked perfectly, not the one you recently posted